# Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 and Git Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

When MS released Git Tools for Visual Studio 2012, they said that it requires Update 2 - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx.

I'm developing some Visual Studio extension and it's interesting for me, what they have changed in Update 2 for Extensions API, that doesn't exist in Update1\RTM.

I checked Update 2 release notes and couldn't find anything related to Extensions work. Source - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912/en-us

Comment: I can't speak for that team, but it's entirely possible there aren't new APIs. They might have just fixed a few bugs that were necessary for everything to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, bug fixing could be a good reason for this requirment.

Answer (score 5):

> > VS Tools for Git requires VS 2012 Update 2 to be installed.

I get the error after VS Update 2 is installed! (Suspect it's because of my locked down local build?)

I installed the vsix file as follows:

- Go to http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c
- Install Visual Studio Update 2 (link under 'Requirements')
- Download the msi
- Extract the GitProvider.vsix from the MSI using LessMSI http://code.google.com/p/lessmsi
- Run the vsix directly

Once installed, you should then see 'Microsoft Git Provider' under Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection

Comment: The question is not how to install it, but why Git tools requries Update2 and what changese there were made that required by Git Tools

Comment: This may be straying from the original topic a bit, but great tip nonetheless! I was running into the same error with VS 2012 Update 3...and the latest version says it requires Update 3. I think it's also worth mentioning that I was also running into this problem on a locked down workstation with limited access rights. I was able to install the MSI without a hitch on another machine with full admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, I haven't found anything as well. Nevertheless when I try to install MS VS Tools for Git I get the error message: `VS Tools for Git requires VS 2012 Update 2 to be installed.`

My config looks like:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 Version 11.0.51106.01 Update
>   1 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709
>
> Installed Version: Professional

Comment: I have similar config. And got the same error message, so just wondering, maybe someone from Microsoft dev team can share there some details about it.